# Import csv file into SQL Server slow because of double loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I want to import a `.csv` file into SQL Server and I need for each value on a given row check it's type to make sure there's no error in the file.

This becomes very slow for large files since I am effectively doing a double loop, for each row, and then for each element in the row.

Is there a faster solution to this problem? I put the current slow code for reference to see if I get some suggestions. Note that schema is a dictionary that defines the data type for each column (i.e, varchar, date, etc.)

```
with open(csv_filename, encoding='utf8') as csv_f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_f)
    idx = 1

    select_code_l = []

    for row in reader:
       # add new value to row
       if d is not None:
           for key,value in d.items():
               row[key] = value
       # get all the values in the schema
       row_values = []
       schema_iterator = schema_df.iterrows()
       for i, schema in schema_iterator:
           schema_name = schema['field']
           value = row[schema2csv[schema_name]]
           #print(value)
           schema_type = schema['type'].split('(')[0].lower()
           if schema_type == 'varchar' or schema_type == 'date' or schema_type == 'datetime2' or schema_type == 'datetime2':
               row_values.append("'"+str(value).replace("'","''")+"'")
           elif schema_type == 'bigint':
               if value == '':
                   row_values.append('NULL')
               else:
                   row_values.append(str(int(float(value))))
           elif schema_type == 'float':
               if value == '':
                   row_values.append('NULL')
               else:
                   row_values.append(str(float(value)))
           else:
               print ('ERROR')
               return 0
```

Comment: You may wish to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), which has a bit of a learning curve, but is very fast.  It's the right tool for this sort of job.

Comment: how many rows do you have in the csv? is this a one-off?

Comment: @criticalfix thanks.  sounds like good advise, I will take a look.  Do you have some fast fix to the messy code above?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn kinda of a one off but would be good to develop some tooling around it cause i feel it will be done many times

Comment: @AndrewMorton row_values is not that long, in  this specific case it's only 52 columns.  I am sending it for each row.

Comment: i would not really waste my time programming this. open in excel and apply a formula in a new column with the insert or the update string with the values accordingly.  if this is a straightforward insert or update.

Comment: if too many rows then use DTS or SSIS (import)

Comment: @Dnaiel Are you sure that it is your program being slow and not the database? For example, if there are indexes on a few columns it might have to do quite a bit of work to insert the data. How is the disk drive doing - is the slowness due to an I/O bottleneck?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn very good points, thanks.

Comment: @AndrewMorton good point.  It could be a connection to Db speed... I will check it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most easy way would be BULK INSERT directly from sql.
If you need some validation, create a cleanup table with the same schema and then get it into the real table with a select query. This is for sure faster.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365.aspx

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
   FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.tbl'  
   WITH   
      (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',  
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'  
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly!  Just Run Bulk Insert, which is super-fast.  Once everything is loaded into the table of your choice (and who cares if there are errors during the load), run a small control check script (or whatever you want to call it) and do your logic testing at this point.  The load into SQL Server will be very fast, and the error checking process will be very fast, once everything is already inside SQL Server.